# React - How to select all checkboxes based on one without using the map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, frontend

I created a simple form in React that displays the submitted data in the console. I created three checkboxes, the first one to mark the two below, and the other two regarding data processing. Is there a way to change the state of two checkboxes by clicking only the "Accept All" checkbox?

I found solutions that worked on checkboxes mapped from array, while my checkboxes are simply written in the code. I can't understand how I can target each of the two checkboxes that I need to make change in based on "Accept all" checkbox

Below is a styled component code that includes Processing div, label, checkbox and text for checkboxes

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Processing = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 24px;

  @media (min-width: ${({ theme }) => theme.tabletPortrait}) {
    flex: 1;
  }
`;

export const Label = styled.label`
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 10px;
`;

export const Checkbox = styled.input`
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
`;

export const CheckboxText = styled.span`
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.white};
`;
```

Here is the Contact.jsx component

```js
import {
  Checkbox,
  CheckboxText,
  Label,
  Processing,
} from './styles/Contact.styled';

const Contact = () => {
  return (
    <Processing>
      <Label>
        <Checkbox type='checkbox' />
        <CheckboxText>Accept all</CheckboxText>
      </Label>
      <Label>
        <Checkbox type='checkbox' defaultChecked={false} required />
        <CheckboxText>I agree to the processing my data</CheckboxText>
      </Label>
      <Label>
        <Checkbox type='checkbox' defaultChecked={false} required />
        <CheckboxText>RODO processing my data by company</CheckboxText>
      </Label>
    </Processing>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

Comment: Where are your `Label`, `Checkbox`, and `CheckboxText` components coming from?

Comment: As I wrote above, they are imported from styled components.

Comment: Yes, but we need to be able to see the structure and logic of those components. Are they from a component library, or custom styled components?

Comment: Got it, edited the question and added styled component and Contact component code. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control the state of another component you will have to use a controlled component. Usually it looks like this:

```
const Contact = () => {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

  // Or whatever your prop names are
  // The point is that Contact decides what the value of the checkbox should be
  // and Checkbox reports back whenever it changes
  return <Checkbox onChange={setIsChecked} value={isChecked} />
};
```

Now the parent component controls the value of the checkbox, it doesn't manage its own state. Which means you can write functions that change that state in the parent component.

```
const Contact = () => {
  const [checks, setChecks] = useState([false, false, false]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (checks[0]) setChecks([true, true, true]);
    else setChecks([false, false, false]);
  }, [checks[0]]);

  const handleOnChange = n => () => {
    // Or however you want to update a single value in a list
    setChecks(c => [...c.slice(0, n), !checks[n], ...c.slice(n + 1)]);
  };

  return (
  <Processing>
    <Label>
      <Checkbox onChange={handleOnChange(0)} type='checkbox' />
      <CheckboxText>Accept all</CheckboxText>
    </Label>
    <Label>
      <Checkbox onChange={handleOnChange(1)} type='checkbox' defaultChecked={false} required />
      <CheckboxText>I agree to the processing my data</CheckboxText>
    </Label>
    <Label>
      <Checkbox onChange={handleOnChange(2)} type='checkbox' defaultChecked={false} required />
      <CheckboxText>RODO processing my data by company</CheckboxText>
    </Label>
  </Processing>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi, I'm new to React and have never heard of controlled component. I'll have to read about it. I tested your code, but unfortunately the 'accept all' checkbox still does not select the other two.

Comment: This code is not for copy pasting. It has to be adapted to your component. I have no idea where your Checkbox component is coming from or what its api is.

Comment: If you show your checkbox impl I can tell you how to make it work.

Comment: Alright, I edited the question, now the code is divided into a styled component and a Contact component

Comment: Ah, it's an input. Looks like you just need to add the `checked` prop to control the checkbox. `<Checkbox checked={checks[0]} ... />`

Comment: I also had to update the handleOnChange function

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! The only thing left is warning ```React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'checks'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.```

Comment: Ah, right. You can't have checks in the dep list cause it will cause an infinite loop. But since you can calculate the new state in the handleChange function, you could remove the effect and add this to handleChange `if (n === 0) return setChecks([!checks[0], !checks[0], !checks[0]]);`.